# How to compare dataframe to a string variable

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, rdd

I have a string variable `dest` which holds a certain value. I need to check if this variable exists on a registered temptable . I use the below query to find it.

```
terminatecheck = sqlContext.sql("""
       SELECT 1 as op from known where node = """+dest +""" and 1=1 
    """)
```

Now i need to compare the value of terminatecheck to "1" and terminate a loop. 
I checked and found that terminatecheck is a row object. How exactly do i compare this ?

```
 if  terminatecheck.op =="1":
```

does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `sqlContext.sql("Select...")` will return a `dataframe` which is lazy evaluated. You need to call an action like `first`, `take` or `collect` to get the expression evaluated and the value returned. You probably want to call `first` which returns a single row (of type `Row`). `take` and `collect` returns an array (of type `Array[Row]`).

```
terminatecheck = sqlContext
    .sql("""SELECT 1 as op from known where node = """+dest +""" and 1=1""")
    .first
```

Comment: I solved it by checking for .count() and it worked too